# JSON double slash in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having an issue with JSON , my intention is to remove slash in starting

> // [ { "id": "207437" ,"t" : "NIFTY" ,"e" : "NSE" ,"l" : "7,955.30"
>   ,"l_fix" : "7955.30" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.7,955.30" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"9:46AM
>   GMT 5:30" ,"lt" : "Oct 1, 9:46AM GMT 5:30" ,"lt_dts" :
>   "2014-10-01T09:46:16Z" ,"c" : "-9.50" ,"c_fix" : "-9.50" ,"cp" :
>   "-0.12" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.12" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "7964.8" }]

How i remove it

Comment: How are you getting this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get JSON data using PHP. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582129/unable-to-get-json-data-using-php-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
$valid_json = substr($invalid_json, 2);
```

---

[**substr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

*(PHP 4, PHP 5)
substr — Return part of a string*

**Description**

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working i used it $valid_json = substr($invalid_json, 3); to remove starting slash...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = ltrim($str, '/ ');
```

That's it.. space is added as it looks that you have it there too.

ps: this is **not a space** there in the google's answer!! code below works.

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:NIFTY,NSE:RELIANCE,NSE:SBIN,NSE:TCS,NSE:ONGC,NSE:HDFC,NSE:ITC%27');
$str = ltrim($str, chr(10).chr(47));
var_dump(json_decode($str));
```

Comment: @user3214110 ltrim cuts the listed symbols at the beginning of the string. In which way do you have your original data?

Comment: my original code---  $url = 'http://finance.xyz.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:NIFTY,NSE:RELIANCE,NSE:SBIN,NSE:TCS,NSE:ONGC,NSE:HDFC,NSE:ITC';
 $file = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: @user3214110 what do you mean by 'my original code'?? do you have it in the string or as an object? Are you sure you don't have other symbols there?