# Why am I unable to get JSON data using PHP?

Tags: php, json

This is the JSON file:

> // [ { "id": "5417778" ,"t" : "TATAMTRDVR" ,"e" : "NSE" ,"l" :
>   "329.80" ,"l_fix" : "329.80" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.329.80" ,"s": "0"
>   ,"ltt":"11:11AM GMT+5:30" ,"lt" : "Jul 26, 11:11AM GMT+5:30" ,"lt_dts"
>   : "2016-07-26T11:11:45Z" ,"c" : "-0.35" ,"c_fix" : "-0.35" ,"cp" :
>   "-0.11" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.11" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "330.15" } ]

And my code is,

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:TATAMTRDVR');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->id;
?>
```

The error message displayed is,

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fin\latest_stock.php on line 4

Comment: `print_r($obj)` and show me what data come from.

Comment: The // are preventing the object from being processed

Comment: @Anant It seems the `//` is included in the output from the url...

Comment: Yes . thanks you reedit it @jeroen. OP hvae to clear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a valid json. Remove "// " from json response and your code will work fine.

Comment: Response coming from http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:TATAMTRDVR has "// " as prefix.

Comment: yeah, I got that. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The object is contained within an array so you need to do this:

```
echo $obj[0]->id;
```

instead of

```
echo $obj->id;
```

Comment: no, it isn't working

Comment: what are you getting

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it looks right to me...

Comment: try echoing your $json after file_get_contents call.

Comment: It seems the url is returning invalid json, so you would need to correct that as well.

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, I got that.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert it into a valid JSON. Remove the slashes ("//") first.

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?     q=NSE:TATAMTRDVR');
$modifiedResponse = str_replace('// ','',$response);
$obj = json_decode($modifiedResponse);
echo $obj[0]->id;
?>
```